# Add/extend behavior of Future created by ListeningExecutorService

Tags: java, guava

The ultimate goal is to add extra behavior to [ListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html)s *based on the type of the `Callable`/`Runnable` argument*.  I want to add extra behavior to each of the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) methods.  (Example use cases can be found in [AbstractExecutorService's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html) and section 7.1.7 of Goetz's [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601))

I have an existing [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which overrides [newTaskFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor(java.util.concurrent.Callable)).  It tests the argument's type and creates a subclass of `FutureTask`.  This naturally supports submit as well as [invokeAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection)) and [invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)).

How do I get the same effect for the [ListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html)s returned by a [ListeningExecutorService](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html)?

Put another way, where can I put this code

```
if (callable instanceof SomeClass) {
   return new FutureTask<T>(callable) {
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            System.out.println("Canceling Task");
            return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        }
    };
} else {
    return new FutureTask<T>(callable);
}
```

such that my client can execute the `println` statement with

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = ...;
Collection<Callable> callables = ImmutableSet.of(new SomeClass());
List<Future<?>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

### Failed Solutions

Here's a list of things I've already tried and why they don't work.

#### Solution A

Pass `MyExecutorService` to  [MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService)).

*Problem 1:* Unfortunately the resulting [ListeningExecutorService](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) (an `AbstractListeningExecutorService`) doesn't delegate to the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) methods, it delegates to the [execute(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) method on [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). As a result, the `newTaskFor` method on `MyExecutorService` is never called.

*Problem 2:* `AbstractListeningExecutorService` creates the Runnable (a [ListenableFutureTask](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFutureTask.html)) via static factory method which I can't extend.

#### Solution B

Inside `newTaskFor`, create `MyRunnableFuture` normally and then wrap it with a `ListenableFutureTask`.

*Problem 1:* [ListenableFutureTask](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFutureTask.html)'s factory methods don't accept [RunnableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html)s, they accept `Runnable` and `Callable`.  If I pass `MyRunnableFuture` as a Runnable, the resulting `ListenableFutureTask` just calls `run()` and not any of the `Future` methods (where my behavior is).

*Problem 2:* Even if it did call my `Future` methods, `MyRunnableFuture` is not a `Callable`, so I have to supply a return value when I create the `ListenableFutureTask`... which I don't have... hence the `Callable`.

#### Solution C

Let MyRunnableFuture extend `ListenableFutureTask` instead of `FutureTask`

*Problem:* `ListenableFutureTask` is now final (as of r10 / r11).

#### Solution D

Let `MyRunnableFuture` extend [ForwardingListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ForwardingListenableFuture.html) and implement [RunnableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html).  Then wrap the `SomeClass` argument in a `ListenableFutureTask` and return that from `delegate()`

*Problem:* It hangs.  I don't understand the problem well enough to explain it, but this configuration causes a deadlock in FutureTask.Sync .

*Source Code:* As requested, here's the source for Solution D which hangs:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.*;

/** See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8931215/290943 */
public final class MyListeningExecutorServiceD extends ThreadPoolExecutor implements ListeningExecutorService {

    // ===== Test Harness =====

    private static interface SomeInterface {
        public String getName();
    }
    
    private static class SomeClass implements SomeInterface, Callable<Void>, Runnable {
        private final String name;

        private SomeClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("SomeClass.call");
            return null;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("SomeClass.run");
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static class MyListener implements FutureCallback<Void> {
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            System.out.println("MyListener.onSuccess");
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("MyListener.onFailure");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Main.start");
        
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass("Main.someClass");
        
        ListeningExecutorService executor = new MyListeningExecutorServiceD();
        Collection<Callable<Void>> callables = ImmutableSet.<Callable<Void>>of(someClass);
        List<Future<Void>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);
        
        for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
            Futures.addCallback((ListenableFuture<Void>) future, new MyListener());
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Main.done");
    }

    // ===== Implementation =====

    private static class MyRunnableFutureD<T> extends ForwardingListenableFuture<T> implements RunnableFuture<T> {

        private final ListenableFuture<T> delegate;
        private final SomeInterface someClass;

        private MyRunnableFutureD(SomeInterface someClass, Runnable runnable, T value) {
            assert someClass == runnable;
            this.delegate = ListenableFutureTask.create(runnable, value);
            this.someClass = someClass;
        }
        
        private MyRunnableFutureD(SomeClass someClass, Callable<T> callable) {
            assert someClass == callable;
            this.delegate = ListenableFutureTask.create(callable);
            this.someClass = someClass;
        }

        @Override
        protected ListenableFuture<T> delegate() {
            return delegate;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("MyRunnableFuture.run");
            try {
                delegate.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            System.out.println("MyRunnableFuture.cancel " + someClass.getName());
            return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        }
    }

    public MyListeningExecutorServiceD() {
        // Same as Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor for now
        super(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
        if (runnable instanceof SomeClass) {
            return new MyRunnableFutureD<T>((SomeClass) runnable, runnable, value);
        } else {
            return new FutureTask<T>(runnable, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        if (callable instanceof SomeClass) {
            return new MyRunnableFutureD<T>((SomeClass) callable, callable);
        } else {
            return new FutureTask<T>(callable);
        }
    }

    /** Must override to supply co-variant return type */
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        return (ListenableFuture<?>) super.submit(task);
    }

    /** Must override to supply co-variant return type */
    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submit(Runnable task, T result) {
        return (ListenableFuture<T>) super.submit(task, result);
    }

    /** Must override to supply co-variant return type */
    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return (ListenableFuture<T>) super.submit(task);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this question and a couple others discussions I've had recently, I'm coming to the conclusion that `RunnableFuture`/`FutureTask` is inherently misleading: Clearly you submit a `Runnable`, and clearly you get a `Future` back, and clearly the underlying `Thread` needs a `Runnable`.  But why should a class implement both `Runnable` and `Future`?  And if it does, which `Runnable` is it replacing?  That's bad enough already, but then we introduce multiple levels of executors, and things really get out of hand.

If there's a solution here, I think it's going to require treating `FutureTask` as an implementation detail of `AbstractExecutorService`.  I'd focus instead on splitting the problem into two pieces:

- I want to conditionally modify the returned `Future`.
- I want to conditionally modify the code run by the executor service.  (I'm actually not sure whether this is a requirement here, but I'll cover it in case it is.  Even if not, it may help establish the `Runnable`/`Future` distinction.)

(grumble Markdown grumble)

```
class MyWrapperExecutor extends ForwardingListeningExecutorService {
  private final ExecutorService delegateExecutor;

  @Override public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
    if (callable instanceof SomeClass) {
      // Modify and submit Callable (or just submit the original Callable):
      ListenableFuture<T> delegateFuture =
          delegateExecutor.submit(new MyCallable(callable));
      // Modify Future:
      return new MyWrapperFuture<T>(delegateFuture);
    } else {
      return delegateExecutor.submit(callable);
    }
  }

  // etc.
}
```

Could that work?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right... this is basically the same solution that I'm settling on (see my answer).  As I mention there, the catch is in `invokeAll`  If I avoid that, then we have a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to ListeningExecutorService [Javadoc](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.html), you can use  MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator to decorate your own ExecutorService.

So use your ExecutorService that overrides newTaskFor, and wrap it with the method above. Would that work for you?

**UPDATE**

Ok, this is what I would do:

1) Download Guava sources if you haven't already.

2) Don't use listeningDecorator, instead, make your custom ExecutorService implement ListeningExecutorService.

3) Your subclass of FutureTask should implement ListenableFuture, and copy the code from ListenableFutureTask, which is quite simple, and then add your cancel method override.

4) Implement the methods of ListeningExecutorService on your custom ExecutorService by changing the returning method of the existing methods to ListenableFuture.

Comment: Unfortunately the resulting `ListeningExecutorService` doesn't delegate to the `ExecutorService` methods, it delegates to the `execute(Runnable)` method on `Executor`.  As a result, the `newTaskFor` method on `MyExecutorService` is never called. 

Furthermore, `AbstractListeningExecutorService` (the implementation used by `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator`) creates the Runnable
via static factory method, which can't be extended.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(service)` will modify the futures returned by your underlying `service`.  So if you've already modified your underlying `ExecutorService`, and you're just decorating the `Future` methods, you may just be able to use `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(service)` directly.  Have you experimented to see if that works?  If not, can you provide more details on why that doesn't work?

----UPDATE----

It appears that your code, as written, mixes up submit and invokeAll.  (Specifically, it calls invokeAll, which doesn't delegate to submit...)

That said, the conclusion I am rapidly drawing is that ListenableFutures and ListeningExecutorService aren't meant to be abused this way.  Implementing this stuff without deadlocks is a Bona Fide Hard Problem, and you're not supposed to do it if you can avoid it.

I suspect that it might be worth filing a Guava issue that Solution A doesn't work, *maybe.*  But I keep trying to figure out how to do what you're doing, and it just feels wrong to do it.

Can you give some insight as to *why* you're trying to return different futures?

Comment: (See edited question for more details) This doesn't work... The Executor created by listeningDecorator doesn't forward calls to the underlying ExecutorService, it only calls `execute(Runnable)` thus bypassing the `newTaskFor` method.

Comment: Okay, convinced.  Could you post your code for Solution D?  I think that's probably the approach you're "supposed to take."

Comment: Source code added to the question... just run main() to see the problem.

Comment: I wish I could be a little more explicit about *why* I need this, but the answer is just "compatibility".  It's functionality that my API offered already, so I'm not sure how it's being used.  Basically, my API says "if your Runnable/Callable implements `SomeInterface`, then I'll invoke the methods on `SomeInterface` when `Future`'s `cancel`, `isDone`, and `isCancelled` methods are invoked".

Comment: Fair enough.  As mentioned above, I endorse cpovirk's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator%28java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService%29) clearly states that it delegates to `execute` and never calls the delegate's `submit`, `invokeAll`, and `invokeAny`.   Furthermore it says that any "special handling of tasks must be implemented in the delegate's `execute` method or by wrapping the returned `ListeningExecutorService`."

So using `newTaskFor` is out.  Period.

I can get most of the behavior that I want by doing (source included below):

1. Move the behavior I want to add to a subclass of `ForwardingListenableFuture` (MyListenableFuture)
2. Let `MyExecutorService` extend `ForwardingListeningExecutorService`
3. Use `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator` to wrap a standard `ExecutorService` *without* the overridden `newTaskFor` method.
4. Override submit to wrap the ListenableFuture returned by the listeningDecorator with MyListenableFuture

The only "gap" I have left is `invokeAll`.  There are two problems:

1. (minor) If I assume the `Future`s returned by `listeningDecorator` are "in the same order" as the `Callable`s that I submitted to it, then I can walk down the list of `Callable`s and `Future`s creating a `MyListenableFuture` for each pair.  This is probably a safe assumption, but still not entirely valid.  (I'd also have to copy the `Callable`s out of my argument to avoid an interleaved mutation, but that's ok)
2. (bigger) `AbstractListeningExecutorService` invokes `cancel`, `isDone`, and `get` within `invokeAll`.  This means that I can't add my behavior to those methods before they're called.

#### Source

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.*;

/** See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8931215/290943 */
public final class MyListeningExecutorServiceE extends ForwardingListeningExecutorService {

    // ===== Test Harness =====

    private static interface SomeInterface {
        public String getName();
    }

    private static class SomeClass implements SomeInterface, Callable<Void>, Runnable {
        private final String name;

        private SomeClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("SomeClass.call");
            return null;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("SomeClass.run");
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static class MyListener implements FutureCallback<Void> {
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            System.out.println("MyListener.onSuccess");
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("MyListener.onFailure");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Main.start");

        SomeInterface someClass = new SomeClass("Main.someClass");

        ListeningExecutorService executor = new MyListeningExecutorServiceE();

        ListenableFuture<Void> future = executor.submit((Callable<Void>) someClass);
        Futures.addCallback(future, new MyListener());
        future.cancel(true);

        /*  Not supported by this implementation

        Collection<Callable<Void>> callables = ImmutableSet.<Callable<Void>>of(someClass);
        List<Future<Void>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);

        for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
            Futures.addCallback((ListenableFuture<Void>) future, new MyListener());
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        */

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Main.done");
    }

    // ===== Implementation =====

    private static class MyListenableFutureE<T> extends ForwardingListenableFuture<T> {

        private final ListenableFuture<T> delegate;
        private final SomeInterface someInterface;

        private MyListenableFutureE(SomeInterface someInterface, ListenableFuture<T> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
            this.someInterface = someInterface;
        }

        @Override
        protected ListenableFuture<T> delegate() {
            return delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            System.out.println("MyRunnableFuture.cancel " + someInterface.getName());
            return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        }
    }

    private final ListeningExecutorService delegate;

    public MyListeningExecutorServiceE() {
        delegate = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    }

    @Override
    protected ListeningExecutorService delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        ListenableFuture<T> future = super.submit(task);

        if (task instanceof SomeInterface) {
            future = new MyListenableFutureE<T>((SomeInterface) task, future);
        }

        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        ListenableFuture<?> future = super.submit(task);

        if (task instanceof SomeInterface) {
            future = new MyListenableFutureE((SomeInterface) task, future);
        }

        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submit(Runnable task, T result) {
        ListenableFuture<T> future = super.submit(task, result);

        if (task instanceof SomeInterface) {
            future = new MyListenableFutureE<T>((SomeInterface) task, future);
        }

        return future;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good catch on the `invokeAll` problems with my previous proposal.

Maybe I'm still overthinking this.  Can `MyRunnableFuture` itself implement `ListenableFuture` and `MyExecutorService` itself implement `ListeningExecutorService`?  You would still extend `AbstractExecutorService`, but you'd declare that you're implementing `ListeningExecutorService`, as well.  Because all the methods of `AbstractExecutorService` use the object returned by `newTaskFor`, and because you know that you'll be returning a `ListenableFuture` from that method, you can simply override all them to declare a return type of `ListenableFuture` and implement them along the lines of `return (ListenableFuture<T>) super.foo()`.

If that would work, perhaps we should make our `AbstractListeningExecutorService` class public and add in some hooks that would make this easier?